# How can I create a file stream?

Tags: c, memory-management, io, filestream

File streams are always acceded through pointers and they are always pre-created. But is it possible to create a file stream inside the program as an object that holds space in memory without using an external file?

My first thought was to declare a `FILE *` pointer then allocate memory for a `FILE` object using `malloc()`:

```
FILE *fileStream = malloc(sizeof(FILE));
```

but I guess this is not right.

How can I do it the right way so I can work with `fileStream` using the I/O functions like `fprintf()` and `fscanf()` ...

Comment: Whats wrong with `fopen`?

Comment: Do you mean you want to treat an in-memory buffer as a file?

Comment: @larsmans Yes exactly like `stdin` ...

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean. `stdin` is a vanilla `FILE*`.

Comment: @larsmans `stdin` is `FILE*` but it's pointing to a space in memory, doesn't it?

Comment: maybe `pipe()` can create a internal `inode` that can be used as a file but has no existence in file system - but it is only for linux i think.

Comment: @Dipto Unfortunately I need something standardized and cross-platform.

Comment: @rullof: yes, it points to a `FILE`. That in turn is a handle on an "actual" file, i.e. a file descriptor in kernel space.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support in C itself for this. You will need to use platform-specific means. If on Unix, you could combine `memmap` and `fdopen`, for instance. For other platforms, see the platform documentation.